# Google sheets: script that copies 2 columns from 1 tab into another tab with more columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps

I have a google sheet with two tabs. Sheet1 has Column A, which is a list of names, which will constantly be added to. One may insert a row in the middle or top of the list and add a name, or simply add at the end of the list. Column B has their ID.
Sheet2 takes Column A and B and then has more columns regarding the people listed (address, phone number, etc). Initially, I had sort commands in place, but then I realized that when I added employee info to the rest of the columns on tab 2, and then added a new row in the first tab, it would not move the rest of the data in the columns past the first two.

I also tried inserting a script that automatically inserts or deletes a row in another tab based on the first tab. but this does not work if I want to add more tabs to the spreadsheet later and use the same list.

I've created a sample spreadsheet to show what the outcome should be like.. but is this possible? If someone adds a row in between names on sheet1, then the same thing should be done on sheet2 and the rest of the data in the other columns should move over as well (Either down or up depending on where the name was inserted in the previous tab).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zVyCEeg5cq35grB3-mDsOwYkYDPx3cSKj8_lyY1BQik/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your example does not work for me because the first sheet has name and id and the second also has name and id and it also has address and phone.  If I am to assume that the second sheet is your final out come then I would ask how did you know how to assign the names and ids to the correct address and phone numbers.  You have not explain that well enough for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking and disregarding what @Cooper has related something like this might be helpful:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
Logger.log(ss.getName());
const sheetname = "Sheet1"
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
const copyToSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");

function myChangeType(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); //DEBUG
  // create some variables from Event Objects
  var type = e.changeType;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
  var editedsheet = e.source.getSheetName();
  Logger.log("DEBUG: The sheet name is " + e.source.getSheetName() + ", and the change type is " + type);
  //var edtitedRange;
  let edtitedRange;
  // which onChange Event occured
  switch (type) {
    case "EDIT":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      // we just copy all the values in the first two columns
      // get all the values as we may have inserted or deleted a row
      // this is due to bug in apps script where range is not provided in onChange=EDIT
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 2).getValues();
      // now copy values to other sheet
      var copyToRange = copyToSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 2);
      copyToRange.setValues(valuesToCopy);
      break;
    case "INSERT_ROW":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
      var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
      var row = range.getLastRow();
      Logger.log("DEBUG: ADDED LastRow: " + row);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: ADDED numberRows: " + numberRows);
      copyToSheet.insertRowsBefore(row, numberRows);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: copyToSheet.insertRowsBefore numberRows: " + numberRows);
      break;
    case "INSERT_COLUMN":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      const colNumber = editedsheet.getSelection().getActiveRange().getColumn();
      edtitedRange = editedsheet.getRange(1, colNumber, editedsheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
      onInsertColumn(edtitedRange);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The activeRng is " + activeRng);
      break;
    case "REMOVE_ROW":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
      var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
      var tValues=range.getValues();
      Logger.log(tValues)
      var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
      Logger.log("DEBUG: DELETED LastRow: " + lastRow);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: DELETED numberRows: " + numberRows);
      //Have to add the top row back
      let topRow = lastRow - numberRows + 1;
      copyToSheet.deleteRows(topRow, numberRows);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: copyToSheet.deleteRows numberRows: " + numberRows);
      break;
    case "REMOVE_COLUMN":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      break;
    case "INSERT_GRID":
      // implies a sheet was added
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      break;
    case "REMOVE_GRID":
      // implies a sheet was deleted
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      break;
    case "FORMAT":
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      break;
    case "OTHER":
      // impiles this was changed by a formula
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + type);
      break;
    default:
      Logger.log("DEBUG: The changeType is " + Unknown);
      break;
  }
}
```